# Set tmux pane title to command used with split-window

Tags: bash, macos, tmux

## Question

is it possible to send the `<command>` given with `new-session` and `split-window`, to the pane title?

### Background

#### tmux command

```sh
tmux \
  new-session -s start  \
    "lerna bootstrap; read" \; \
  split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}" \
    "yarn api:setup; read" \; \
  split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}" \
    "yarn api:start; read" \; \
  split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}" \
    "yarn spa:start; read" \; \
  split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}" \
    "yarn spa:deps:build; read" \; \
  select-layout even-vertical
```

#### ~/.tmux.conf

```sh
set -g pane-border-format "#P: #{pane_current_command}"
```

### Pane titles

#### Current

```
──0: bash─────────────────────

──1: bash─────────────────────

──2: bash─────────────────────
```

#### Desired

```
──0: lerna bootstrap; read─────────────────────

──1: yarn api:setup; read─────────────────────

──2: yarn api:start; read─────────────────────
```

etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use #{pane_start_command} but it will obviously not update as the running command changes.